# Can an Armorer artificer using the Guardian armor model wield a shield or weapon in one Thunder Gauntlet, and still attack with the other gauntlet?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, artificer

This question is about the [Armorer artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Armorer)'s [Armor Model](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ArmorModel-2985544) feature. The description of the Guardian armor model's Thunder Gauntlets says (TCoE, p. 16):

> **Thunder Gauntlets.** Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren't holding anything in it, and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on a hit. A creature hit by the gauntlet has disadvantage on attack rolls against targets other than you until the start of your next turn, as the armor magically emits a distracting pulse when the creature attacks someone else.

Can you wield a shield (or weapon) with one gauntlet, and still make the special attack with your other hand? Or do I need both gauntlets free to do this?

Answer (score 9):

#### Each gauntlet is an individual melee weapon.

The Thunder Gauntlets state:

> Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren't holding anything in **it**.

This indicates that each gauntlet is individually a simple melee weapon, each wielded in one hand.

So you can wield something in one hand and use a Thunder Gauntlet with the other, with all the benefits a Thunder Gauntlet brings.

Comment: It's important to note that all the normal rules for two-weapon fighting still apply, and the Thunder Gauntlets aren't *light* weapons.