# Can an Armorer Artificer infuse both of their Thunder Gauntlets separately?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

This takes a little setup...

At level 3, an Artificer takes the Armorer sub-class. One of the features is Armor Model which can be configured so that they have Thunder Gauntlets.

> **Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren't holding anything in it**, and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on a hit.

They technically have two weapons as discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180739/38834) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/183617/38834). So they can attack with one fist or the other. And at level 5, they get Extra Attack and can either punch twice with one hand or once with each hand [Discussed here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192434/38834)

At level 9, their armor gets an upgrade:

> You learn how to use your artificer infusions to specially modify your Arcane Armor. That armor now counts as separate items for the purposes of your Infuse Items feature: armor (the chest piece), boots, helmet, and the armor's special weapon. Each of those items can bear one of your infusions, and the infusions transfer over if you change your armor's model with the Armor Model feature.

### Can each gauntlet be infused with its own infusion?

Since the description says, "the armor's special weapon," and the special weapon is/are the pair of gauntlets, each of which is a weapon in its own right. I would think it's possible.

Can the Artificer infuse one gauntlet with "Enhanced Weapon" and the other with "Radiant Weapon"?

Answer (score 4):

### Likely not, but up to DM judgement

The Armor Model text (p. 16 TCE) says:

> You can customize your Arcane Armor. When you do so, choose one of the following armor models: Guardian or Infiltrator. The model you choose gives you special benefits while you wear it. Each model includes **a special weapon**. When you attack with **that weapon**

The special weapon is referred to as a singular weapon. So even if you have two gauntlets, they together constitute your "special weapon". While the individual gauntlets may be treated as two separate weapons for the purpose of attack, for the purpose of your artificer magic and infusions, the pair of ***Thunder Gauntlets*** is your special weapon.

This language is consistent. The section you cite again talks about the weapon in singluar, and states "the weapon" can bear **one** of your infusions:

> armor (the chest piece), boots, helmet, and **the armor's special weapon**. Each of those items can bear **one** of your infusions,

It's also unlikely that it is an oversight, as there are only two options for Arcane Armor in TCE. If the rules wanted to treat each gauntlet as a separate special weapon and allow multiple infusions, it would have been easy to use the plural and say "the armor's special weapons". For the other armor, that has only a single Lightning Launcher as its weapon, this would not have made any difference.

Now, you are quite the expert yourself in Artificer rules, considering some of the answers to the other questions you cite are yours. That you even have this question by itself is a good indication that it is not super clear-cut. I do think it would be defensible for a DM to rule the other way and declare each gauntlet being their own weapon, separately infusible. Also power wise, having a different effect on each hand seems unproblematic, considering you are spending an extra infusion slot to do so. And it may make for a cool character feel, similar to the elf from [Black Moon Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Moon_Chronicles) with his frostbrand and flame tongue swords.

Comment: If the pair of thunder gauntlets counts as a single weapon, can one infusion apply to both of them..?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, yes I would think so. I would enchance both of them with the same bonus.

Comment: I don't think I can agree with the premise that "the armor's special weapons" would work. If I read "weapons" I would think there are multiple weapons; like one melee and one range weapon for each model. But each Armor Model only has one line item for weapon; either Thunder Gauntlets or Lightning Launcher. LL can be a range weapon on either one glove OR a chest piece. The main paragraph states, _"Each model includes a special weapon."_ So having singular makes sense. But TG is one line item that states that each glove is a weapon, and that matches with the other Q&A I linked.

Comment: One of the key phrases is "counts as separate items". The armor doesn't literally *become* separate items for infusion, it only counts as separate items, so it doesn't matter how many weapons are actually built in to the armor, it counts as one infusable weapon (in addition to other infusable things) because that's what the feature says.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson, you should put that as an answer